# Divide two floating values give zero

Tags: java, double

I have been in the python and scala world for sometime so not having reply or interpreter is really giving me nightmares of debugging. I have following code:

```
int count = someInteger;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    if(!entry.getKey().equals("20") && top5 < 5) {
        String movie = entry.getKey();
        int xandy = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(movie + "," + Float.toString(xandy / count));
        top5 += 1;
    }
}
```

The issue here is that I get zero from the devision. I thought I have handle the type variables correctly. I have tried the answers provided but still doesn't work but the problem is still getting zero:

Could this be causing the issue:

```
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: You have two ints there, where are two floating values?

Comment: xandy and count are integers, they cannot return decimals so it returns 0 and then you get 0f

Comment: so if i do this it should work right `(float)xandy / (float)count;` but it doesn't

Comment: Print the  `xandy` by itself to make sure it's not zero.  Also you can see variable values when you run under debugger.

Comment: I think the issue is `System.out.println(movie + "," + Float.toString((float)xandy / (float)count));` because when I isolate the division it works. Strange.

Comment: I suggest you use `double` not `float` as the later has very poor precision. try `System.out.println(movie + "," + (double) xandy / count);`

Comment: Please update the post with the current code and what happens if you print xandy ?

Comment: Why is Float.toString necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int count = someInteger;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    if(!entry.getKey().equals("20") && top5 < 5) {
        String movie = entry.getKey();
        int xandy = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(movie + "," + Float.toString((float)xandy / (float)count));
        top5 += 1;
    }
}
```

Note the float cast for xandy and count

Comment: While this is correct, `cast` on one on the integers would've been enough.

Comment: Didn't work I am starting to wonder Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. if this has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: Can you print xandy before trying to divide? If xandy is 0 then 0 will be the result.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing integer division in Java, which results in an integer, so any decimal part of the division is truncated.

To get the floating-point quotient, first cast one of the variables as a `float` or a `double` so floating-point division will occur.

```
((float) xandy / count)
```

According to the [JLS, Section 15.17.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2):

> Integer division rounds toward 0. That is, the quotient produced for
>   operands n and d that are integers after binary numeric promotion
>   (§5.6.2) is an integer value q whose magnitude is as large as possible
>   while satisfying |d · q| ≤ |n|. Moreover, q is positive when |n| ≥ |d|
>   and n and d have the same sign, but q is negative when |n| ≥ |d| and n
>   and d have opposite signs.

Casting one of them to `float` is enough.  Java will promote the other operand to a `float` to match types, then perform the division.